# Sqlite not inserting data once the application is stopped and execute again iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, database, sqlite

Im developing a simple application in which it is creating a sqlite database and insert data into it.
It is working fine and the data is insert into the table.

But when i stop the application(in xcode) and run again the data is not inserting into the database.

This is the code i used:

```
+(DBManager*)getSharedInstance{
    if (!sharedInstance) {
        sharedInstance = [[super allocWithZone:NULL]init];
        [sharedInstance createDB];
    }
    return sharedInstance;
}


-(BOOL)createDB{
    NSString *docsDir;
    NSArray *dirPaths;
    // Get the documents directory
    dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains
    (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    docsDir = dirPaths[0];
    // Build the path to the database file
    databasePath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:
                    [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"SchedulerDataBase.db"]];
    BOOL isSuccess = YES;
    NSFileManager *filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    if ([filemgr fileExistsAtPath: databasePath ] == NO)
    {
        const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];
        if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &database) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            char *errMsg;
            const char *sql_stmt ="create table if not exists Scheduler (Date integer primary key,Event text)";
            if (sqlite3_exec(database, sql_stmt, NULL, NULL, &errMsg)
                != SQLITE_OK)
            {
                isSuccess = NO;
                NSLog(@"Failed to create table");
            }
            sqlite3_close(database);
            return  isSuccess;
        }
        else {
            isSuccess = NO;
            NSLog(@"Failed to open/create database");
        }
    }
    return isSuccess;
}

-(BOOL)saveData:(int)date withEvent:(NSString *)event
{
    const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];
    if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &database) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"insert into Scheduler (Date, Event) values(\"%d\", \"%@\")",date,event];
        const char *insert_stmt = [insertSQL UTF8String];
        sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, insert_stmt,-1, &statement, NULL);
        if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE)
        {
            return YES;
        }
        else {
            return NO;
        }
        sqlite3_reset(statement);
    }
    return NO;
}
```

When i stopped the project and then tried to save into database it is always entering 
in the else condition of this loop.

```
if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE)
            {
                return YES;
            }
            else {
                return NO;
            }
```

Can anyone please help me with this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you check the return value of sqlite3_prepare_v2()? Is it SQLITE_OK in both the cases?

Comment: When is the `saveData:withEvent:` method called?

Comment: I'd suggest you first check to see if your startup code is going down the right path with regard to creating the DB.

Comment: @AnkitJain in the first case it is returning YES.In the second case it is returning is NO.

Comment: @TomHarrington it is saving in -(void)textViewDidChange:(TextView *)textview{

Answer (score 0):

In your save data method, it looks like you're never finalizing your statement or closing your database

```
sqlite3_finalize(statement);
sqlite3_close (_database);
```

Perhaps your database is still locked from the previous save attempt.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you only get the database path when you createDB, if you launch your program and don't call `createDB`. you won't `saveData`.

You have to add to you saveData the following code:

```
NSString *docsDir;
NSArray *dirPaths;
// Get the documents directory
dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains
(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
docsDir = dirPaths[0];
// Build the path to the database file
databasePath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:
                [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"SchedulerDataBase.db"]];
```

or just create a method like `-(NSString *)openDB` that returns the above databasePath and use it in the first line of you saveData code like:

```
const char *dbpath = [[self openDB] UTF8String];
```